# What happens to reflections when the distance between a capacitors plates is electrically long?

Tags: transmission-line, high-frequency, modeling

I understand what happens when a transmission line is terminated with a capacitor but what about when the distance between the plates becomes electrically long?

For PCB mounted capacitors I know this distance is tiny, so lets say define a model. A capacitor with a plate separation of 0.1m and plates of 0.1m on each side, a dielectric permittivity of 50, connected between a 1m 50-ohm cable and ground.

I think frequencies >1GHz will have an electrical length of less than the plate seperation?

Particularly I am interested in:

- What does the time domain signal look like for a step travelling along this transmission line?
- What happens to the magnitude/phase of the signal as the frequency is swept?

I am not sure how to model this.

Comment: This might be a good question for Dr. Howard Johnson.  http://www.sigcon.com/

Comment: Thank you @Aaron I have reached out to him

Comment: Considering "capacitor" as a load line (10 cm) which have only the epsilon changed?

Comment: @Antonio51 I am familiar with load lines with finding bias points for transistors but I don't think that is what you mean here. Would you be able to elaborate?

Comment: Ok. I guess that the capacitor is (for example) a cube (1x1x10 cm) as "load" for a transmission line. If you want a "lumped" equivalent at 300 MHz, just divide it into "length" < lambda / 10 (here, 10 sections of length 1 cm). (First try, however ... because of the geometry of your "capacitor", this should be done with EM software ...)

Comment: NB: complete geometry needed?

Comment: Don't you mean electrically long in your title? For instance, a regular capacitor at regular frequencies will have a gap that is totally electrically short.

Comment: @Andyaka you are correct. I do mean electrically long; the title will be updated.

Comment: Geometry has been defined in the question

Comment: Did you also mean to correct the first paragraph?

Comment: I meant "how is wired the coaxial to the capacitor". Do you wire the coaxial at the center of the plates or at one border or coin? As all "sides" have 10 cm ... you need separate the wires on 10 cm (2x5cm) minimum or 2x10cm ... which is a "perfect" antenna already at 100 MHz. And as the speed in the dielectric is v=c/sqrt(50), the lambda (v/f) is divided by ~7. That is why I asked about the "geometry" of wiring. But perhaps I am wrong ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, you get waveguide modes.  Or for plates of indefinite extent, 2D propagation modes.  The step response will include reflections from within the plate area (any nonuniformity within it, or its edges), as well as dispersion from the nonuniform velocity of the waveguide modes (if applicable; I forget if this is true of 2D modes, but it is of the 1D case i.e. waveguide as such), and radiation from the plate edges, and any relevant emissions from the TL-plate transition structure.

This is indeed relevant to PCB design, as parallel planes, fed by a via (say the power pin from a device), share the same description.  Here, the spacing is fairly small compared to most wavelengths, and there is dielectric loading (and at that, FR-4 isn't an especially good dielectric in the GHz), so the impedance is low, and it is effective for power distribution purposes.  They can exhibit waveguide modes at higher frequencies, which is why stitching vias are recommended around high frequency transmission lines (the vias reflect incident low-frequency waves, such that only waves on order of the distance between vias can propagate).

Note that "stitching", between power planes, must be done by bypass caps on vias.  Since a direct via between them would be a short circuit.  The bypass cap serves as an AC short circuit, at modest cost to its impedance (usually a small inductive loop is formed between the two vias, connecting traces/pads, and component body).

This is only a superficial, hand-waved, qualitative explanation; but as exact answers are difficult to produce anyway, the upshot is, when you do need accuracy, you'll simply plug the geometry into a field solver such as HFSS and see how it goes.